# url rewrite: how can i change /news.php?l=world to /news/cat/world

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need help with htaccess. I need to rewrite url of file `http://mydomain.com/news.php?l=world` to `news/cat/world`.
thank you

Comment: @TheReader, basic mod_rewrite configuration questions *are* on-topic here.  This is a dupe *a million times over* with zero research effort, but it's not off-topic.

Comment: @Charles Thanks. Was not aware. Retracted my vote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/cat/([^/]+)/?$ /news.php?l=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```